# How to set minutes as units in Highstock chart using data from CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to get a highstock chart to show minutes on the x axis. My first column in csv data is minutes. I think I have the rangeSelector options correct, but I can't figure out how to make the x axis be the minutes from my csv.

Most of the solutions I see fill x axis with Date.UTC(xx, xx, xx, xx) or similar. But I need it to be filled with minutes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Data from innerHTML of hidden div</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 40px;
        }

        pre {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Highcharts related imports -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> -->

    <!-- Highstock related imports  -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 800px; margin: 2em auto; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 0.5em">
        Highcharts data load from a csv stored inline in a hidden div
    </div>

    <div id="container" style="width:100wv; min-width: 310px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <pre id="csv" style="display:none">Minutes,Y1,Y2
        1,5,120
        2,4,121
        3,4,120
        4,3,119
        5,4,118
        6,4,118
        7,5,118
        8,5,117
        9,6,118
        10,5,117
        11,6,118
        12,5,117
        13,5,116
        14,6,115
        15,5,116
        16,5,115
        17,4,114
        18,3,113
        19,2,113
        20,3,112
        21,4,112
        22,4,111
        23,5,111
        24,4,110
        25,4,109
        26,4,108
        27,5,107
        28,6,108
        29,7,108
        30,8,108
        31,8,108
        32,8,107
        33,7,106
        34,8,106
        35,7,107
        36,6,108
        37,7,108
        38,7,107
        39,6,107
        40,6,108
        41,5,109
        42,4,108
        43,4,108
        44,5,109
        45,6,110
        46,7,109
        47,8,110
        48,8,110
        49,7,111
        50,7,110
        51,6,110
        52,7,109
        53,7,110
        54,6,109
        55,7,108
        56,7,107
        57,6,108
        58,6,107
        59,7,108
        60,6,107
        61,5,108
        62,6,107
        63,6,107
        64,6,107
        65,5,108
        66,4,109
        67,5,108
        68,6,107
        69,5,108
        70,4,109
        71,5,109
        72,6,109
        73,7,109
        74,6,108
        75,5,109
        76,4,108
        77,3,108
        78,4,108
        79,5,107
        80,6,108
        81,7,108
        82,6,107
        83,7,107
        84,6,108
        85,7,109
        86,6,110
        87,6,110
        88,6,109
        89,5,109
        90,5,108
        91,4,109
        92,3,108
        93,3,109
        94,3,109
        95,3,109
        96,3,109
        97,4,109
        98,3,110
        99,3,111
        100,4,110
        101,3,110
        102,2,111
        103,2,112
        104,2,112
        105,1,112
        106,2,112
        107,2,113
        108,3,113
        109,4,114
        110,4,113
        111,4,112
        112,4,112
        113,5,111
        114,5,112
        115,6,111
        116,6,112
        117,7,112
        118,8,111
        119,7,111
        120,6,110
        121,5,111
        122,4,111
        123,5,110
        124,6,109
        125,6,109
        126,5,109
        127,4,109
        128,3,110
        129,2,111
        130,1,111
        131,0,111
        132,0,112
        133,1,111
        134,0,112
        135,0,113
        136,0,112
        137,0,111
        138,0,112
        139,1,112
        140,0,113
        141,0,112
        142,0,111
        143,0,111
        144,1,111
        145,2,110
        146,1,111
        147,0,110
        148,1,109
        149,0,109
        150,0,110
        151,1,109
        152,2,110
        153,1,110
        154,2,109
        155,3,110
        156,3,111
        157,4,112
        158,5,111
        159,4,112
        160,5,111
        161,4,111
        162,5,110
        163,5,109
        164,5,109
        165,5,109
        166,4,110
        167,5,111
        168,6,111
        169,6,112
        170,6,113
        171,7,113
        172,8,114
        173,9,115
        174,10,114
        175,11,115
        176,11,116
        177,11,117
        178,11,116
        179,10,116
        180,9,117
        181,9,116
        182,9,117
        183,8,118
        184,7,119
        185,8,120
        186,7,121
        187,6,122
        188,7,122
        189,6,121
        190,5,121
        191,4,120
        192,4,119
        193,4,120
        194,4,119
        195,3,119
        196,4,120
        197,5,119
        198,4,119
        199,3,118
        200,2,119
        201,1,118
        202,0,117
        203,0,116
        204,1,115
        205,2,114
        206,3,114
        207,3,114
        208,4,115
        209,3,116
        210,4,116
        211,4,116
        212,3,116
        213,2,115
        214,2,115
        215,3,116
        216,4,116
        217,5,115
        218,6,115
        219,7,115
        220,6,114
        221,7,114
        222,7,114
        223,7,113
        224,7,114
        225,7,114
        226,6,114
        227,5,115
        228,5,114
        229,6,115
        230,7,114
        231,6,115
        232,7,114
        233,6,115
        234,5,116
        235,4,116
        236,3,116
        237,4,115
        238,3,116
        239,2,115
        240,1,116
        241,2,117
        242,3,116
        243,4,116
        244,3,115
        245,3,115
        246,4,114
        247,3,115
        248,2,115
        249,3,116
        250,4,116
        251,4,117
        252,4,117
        253,4,118
        254,3,118
        255,2,118
        256,2,118
        257,3,118
        258,4,119
        259,4,118
        260,5,117
        261,4,118
        262,4,117
        263,4,117
        264,4,116
        265,3,116
        266,3,116
        267,2,116
        268,2,115
        269,1,116
        270,1,117
        271,2,116
        272,1,115
        273,2,115
        274,1,115
        275,0,115
        276,0,114
        277,1,113
        278,0,113
        279,0,114
        280,0,115
        281,0,114
        282,1,115
        283,2,115
        284,3,115
        285,4,114
        286,4,115
        287,5,114
        288,5,114
        289,5,114
        290,4,114
        291,4,115
        292,4,114
        293,5,113
        294,6,112
        295,6,112
        296,5,112
        297,4,111
        298,3,110
        299,2,111
        300,3,110
        301,4,109
        302,3,108
        303,3,108
        304,2,109
        305,2,108
        306,3,108
        307,3,109
        308,4,108
        309,4,109
        310,4,108
        311,4,108
        312,5,108
        313,6,107
        314,7,106
        315,6,105
        316,7,106
        317,8,107
        318,9,107
        319,10,107
        320,10,108
        321,9,107
        322,8,108
        323,7,107
        324,8,107
        325,8,108
        326,8,107
        327,9,107
        328,10,106
        329,10,106
        330,9,107
        331,10,108
        332,9,107
        333,10,107
        334,9,107
        335,9,108
        336,8,109
        337,8,108
        338,7,109
        339,6,110
        340,6,109
        341,7,109
        342,7,108
        343,8,108
        344,8,107
        345,7,106
        346,7,105
        347,8,105
        348,9,104
        349,10,105
        350,11,106
        351,11,106
        352,11,106
        353,12,107
        354,13,106
        355,14,106
        356,15,107
        357,16,106
        358,16,106
        359,16,107
        360,17,106
        361,16,105
        362,15,106
        363,16,107
        364,15,107
        365,14,106
        366,13,106
        367,12,107
        368,13,108
        369,14,109
        370,13,110
        371,13,111
        372,13,111
        373,14,112
        374,15,113
        375,16,114
        376,16,114
        377,17,115
        378,16,116
        379,15,117
        380,14,118
        381,15,119
        382,16,119
        383,17,120
        384,16,120
        385,16,120
        386,17,119
        387,17,119
        388,17,120
        389,16,121
        390,17,122
        391,16,121
        392,16,121
        393,15,122
        394,14,123
        395,15,123
        396,16,123
        397,15,122
        398,15,123
        399,14,123
        400,15,122
        401,14,122
        402,14,122
        403,13,122
        404,13,122
        405,14,122
        406,13,122
        407,13,122
        408,14,122
        409,15,122
        410,16,122
        411,16,122
        412,15,122
        413,16,121
        414,15,120
        415,16,120
        416,15,121
        417,14,120
        418,13,121
        419,14,121
        420,14,122
        421,15,122
        422,14,121
        423,14,121
        424,14,122
        425,15,121
        426,16,121
        427,15,121
        428,14,120
        429,13,119
        430,13,118
        431,14,118
        432,14,119
        433,13,118
        434,13,119
        435,14,120
        436,14,121
        437,15,121
        438,16,121
        439,17,121
        440,16,120
        441,15,119
        442,14,118
        443,13,117
        444,12,117
        445,11,117
        446,11,118
        447,10,118
        448,9,118
        449,10,117
        450,10,117
        451,10,116
        452,11,115
        453,11,116
        454,12,115
        455,11,116
        456,11,115
        457,12,116
        458,13,116
        459,13,117
        460,13,116
        461,13,117
        462,12,118
        463,13,119
        464,12,120
        465,13,120
        466,12,120
        467,13,121
        468,12,121
        469,13,120
        470,14,119
        471,14,119
        472,15,119
        473,14,119
        474,15,119
        475,15,120
        476,14,121
        477,13,120
        478,14,119
        479,13,119
        480,13,119
        481,14,119
        482,14,120
        483,13,120
        484,13,119
        485,12,120
        486,12,120
        487,12,121
        488,12,120
        489,13,121
        490,12,121
        491,12,121
        492,11,122
        493,10,121
        494,10,120
        495,10,119
        496,9,119
        497,8,120
        498,9,120
        499,9,120
        500,10,120
        501,10,119
        502,11,119
        503,11,119
        504,10,119
        505,9,118
        506,8,119
        507,8,119
        508,8,120
        509,9,120
        510,10,119
        511,10,119
        512,10,119
        513,11,118
        514,10,118
        515,11,119
        516,10,119
        517,10,118
        518,11,119
        519,12,120
        520,13,121
        521,12,122
        522,13,121
        523,14,121
        524,14,121
        525,14,121
        526,13,122
        527,12,121
        528,11,120
        529,11,120
        530,10,119
        531,9,120
        532,10,119
        533,10,118
        534,10,118
        535,10,119
        536,9,120
        537,9,119
        538,8,119
        539,7,120
        540,6,119
        541,5,118
        542,5,117
        543,5,117
        544,5,116
        545,6,116
        546,7,116
        547,8,115
        548,9,114
        549,10,113
        550,9,114
        551,9,113
        552,8,113
        553,9,112
        554,8,113
        555,9,113
        556,10,112
        557,11,112
        558,11,113
        559,10,113
        560,11,114
        561,11,114
        562,10,114
        563,10,114
        564,10,113
        565,11,113
        566,11,112
        567,12,113
        568,13,112
        569,12,111
        570,13,110
        571,14,110
        572,13,111
        573,14,110
        574,14,111
        575,15,111
        576,16,111
        577,15,111
        578,14,110
        579,15,110
        580,14,110
        581,15,109
        582,15,110
        583,16,110
        584,17,110
        585,16,111
        586,15,110
        587,15,109
        588,15,109
        589,14,109
        590,13,108
        591,13,108
        592,12,109
        593,12,110
        594,11,109
        595,10,109
        596,9,109
        597,10,109
        598,10,110
        599,11,109
        600,12,110
        601,12,111
        602,13,110
        603,14,109
        604,15,108
        605,16,109
        606,17,110
        607,16,111
        608,17,110
        609,18,111
        610,17,112
        611,18,113
        612,18,114
        613,19,113
        614,20,113
        615,21,114
        616,20,114
        617,21,114
        618,20,115
        619,19,116
        620,20,115
        621,20,114
        622,20,114
        623,21,114
        624,21,114
        625,20,114
        626,20,114
        627,20,115
        628,19,116
        629,18,117
        630,18,118
        631,17,119
        632,16,118
        633,16,119
        634,16,119
        635,15,118
        636,15,118
        637,14,119
        638,14,119
        639,15,119
        640,14,118
        641,13,119
        642,12,120
        643,11,120
        644,10,120
        645,9,121
        646,9,121
        647,8,122
        648,9,123
        649,10,123
        650,11,122
        651,11,122
        652,10,122
        653,10,123
        654,11,122
        655,11,122
        656,11,123
        657,10,122
        658,10,122
        659,11,121
        660,12,122
        661,13,122
        662,13,122
        663,13,121
        664,14,122
        665,14,121
        666,14,120
        667,15,120
        668,15,121
        669,16,122
        670,17,123
        671,16,124
        672,17,123
        673,16,122
        674,17,121
        675,17,121
        676,18,120
        677,19,121
        678,19,122
        679,19,121
        680,20,122
        681,19,121
        682,19,121
        683,19,120
        684,20,120
        685,20,119
        686,20,120
        687,20,119
        688,20,118
        689,19,117
        690,19,117
        691,18,116
        692,18,117
        693,18,117
        694,18,117
        695,18,117
        696,18,117
        697,18,117
        698,17,117
        699,16,116
        700,17,115
        701,18,116
        702,17,115
        703,17,116
        704,16,117
        705,17,117
        706,17,117
        707,18,117
        708,18,116
        709,18,115
        710,19,114
        711,20,113
        712,20,113
        713,20,113
        714,20,114
        715,21,113
        716,21,114
        717,20,114
        718,20,115
        719,21,114
        720,22,113
        721,21,113
        722,21,112
        723,22,112
        724,21,111
        725,22,110
        726,23,109
        727,23,109
        728,23,109
        729,24,108
        730,23,109
        731,24,109
        732,23,110
        733,22,109
        734,23,108
        735,22,108
        736,22,107
        737,21,107
        738,20,107
        739,19,106
        740,19,106
        741,19,105
        742,19,104
        743,20,105
        744,20,106
        745,20,107
        746,20,107
        747,21,107
        748,22,108
        749,22,107
        750,21,107
        751,22,106
        752,22,107
        753,22,106
        754,22,106
        755,21,105
        756,22,104
        757,22,105
        758,21,104
        759,20,105
        760,21,104
        761,21,103
        762,22,102
        763,21,101
        764,20,101
        765,20,102
        766,20,102
        767,19,102
        768,18,101
        769,17,100
        770,16,100
        771,16,101
        772,16,101
        773,15,100
        774,14,99
        775,13,100
        776,13,100
        777,12,101
        778,13,102
        779,12,101
        780,13,100
        781,12,101
        782,11,100
        783,11,99
        784,12,99
        785,11,98
        786,11,97
        787,12,97
        788,13,96
        789,13,96
        790,14,95
        791,14,96
        792,14,96
        793,15,96
        794,14,96
        795,14,97
        796,15,98
        797,15,97
        798,15,96
        799,16,95
        800,15,94
        801,15,95
        802,14,96
        803,13,97
        804,14,97
        805,13,98
        806,13,97
        807,12,97
        808,13,98
        809,13,99
        810,14,100
        811,15,99
        812,15,98
        813,16,99
        814,17,100
        815,16,99
        816,17,100
        817,16,100
        818,15,99
        819,14,98
        820,13,97
        821,14,98
        822,13,98
        823,12,97
        824,11,96
        825,11,95
        826,10,95
        827,9,96
        828,8,95
        829,8,96
        830,8,97
        831,8,96
        832,8,95
        833,7,95
        834,8,94
        835,9,95
        836,10,96
        837,10,97
        838,11,96
        839,11,97
        840,11,97
        841,10,97
        842,10,96
        843,11,97
        844,12,96
        845,13,96
        846,13,95
        847,12,94
        848,11,95
        849,12,96
        850,12,96
        851,11,96
        852,10,95
        853,9,95
        854,10,94
        855,11,94
        856,12,94
        857,13,95
        858,13,96
        859,13,97
        860,13,98
        861,12,97
        862,13,98
        863,14,97
        864,15,97
        865,15,98
        866,16,97
        867,17,98
        868,18,97
        869,18,98
        870,18,97
        871,18,97
        872,19,96
        873,19,97
        874,20,98
        875,20,98
        876,19,98
        877,18,98
        878,17,97
        879,18,96
        880,19,96
        881,18,97
        882,17,96
        883,18,97
        884,17,96
        885,16,96
        886,17,96
        887,17,96
        888,17,97
        889,16,98
        890,17,97
        891,18,96
        892,18,97
        893,17,97
        894,16,98
        895,15,97
        896,16,96
        897,16,95
        898,16,94
        899,16,95
        900,16,96
        901,15,96
        902,15,96
        903,15,95
        904,14,95
        905,14,94
        906,13,93
        907,13,94
        908,12,93
        909,11,92
        910,10,91
        911,9,90
        912,9,90
        913,8,90
        914,8,90
        915,9,90
        916,9,89
        917,8,89
        918,9,89
        919,10,90
        920,10,90
        921,11,90
        922,10,89
        923,9,89
        924,8,89
        925,7,88
        926,7,88
        927,8,88
        928,8,88
        929,7,88
        930,8,87
        931,8,87
        932,7,86
        933,8,86
        934,7,86
        935,6,87
        936,7,88
        937,8,88
        938,9,88
        939,10,89
        940,9,89
        941,9,88
        942,9,89
        943,10,90
        944,9,89
        945,9,90
        946,10,90
        947,11,91
        948,11,90
        949,12,91
        950,12,91
        951,12,91
        952,13,91
        953,13,90
        954,14,91
        955,15,90
        956,16,89
        957,17,90
        958,17,91
        959,17,90
        960,18,91
        961,19,91
        962,18,92
        963,17,91
        964,16,92
        965,17,91
        966,17,91
        967,17,91
        968,16,91
        969,16,92
        970,17,91
        971,16,90
        972,17,91
        973,18,90
        974,17,89
        975,16,89
        976,17,88
        977,18,88
        978,19,87
        979,19,87
        980,18,88
        981,18,89
        982,18,89
        983,17,88
        984,17,89
        985,17,90
        986,17,91
        987,17,90
        988,16,91
        989,16,92
        990,17,92
        991,18,91
        992,18,90
        993,17,90
        994,17,89
        995,16,89
        996,15,88
        997,14,89
        998,13,90
        999,13,91
        1000,12,92
        1001,12,91
        1002,12,92
        1003,11,92
        1004,12,93
        1005,12,93
        1006,12,92
        1007,12,92
        1008,11,92
        1009,12,91
        1010,12,90
        1011,12,90
        1012,13,91
        1013,13,91
        1014,12,91
        1015,11,91
        1016,11,92
        1017,12,91
        1018,12,91
        1019,13,92
        1020,14,93
        1021,13,94
        1022,13,95
        1023,12,95
        1024,12,95
        1025,12,94
        1026,11,95
        1027,10,95
        1028,9,96
        1029,9,95
        1030,9,94
        1031,10,94
        1032,11,93
        1033,11,94
        1034,10,94
        1035,9,93
        1036,10,94
        1037,10,93
        1038,10,93
        1039,10,93
        1040,11,94
        1041,10,93
        1042,10,92
        1043,11,93
        1044,11,93
        1045,11,92
        1046,12,91
        1047,12,92
        1048,13,93
        1049,14,92
        1050,13,93
        1051,14,93
        1052,14,93
        1053,14,92
        1054,15,91
        1055,15,90
        1056,16,90
        1057,16,91
        1058,15,92
        1059,14,91
        1060,13,92
        1061,14,92
        1062,13,93
        1063,12,92
        1064,11,93
        1065,11,93
        1066,12,93
        1067,13,92
        1068,13,92
        1069,14,91
        1070,14,92
        1071,13,92
        1072,12,91
        1073,11,92
        1074,11,93
        1075,11,93
        1076,12,94
        1077,13,93
        1078,12,93
        1079,11,94
        1080,12,93
        1081,13,94
        1082,14,94
        1083,13,95
        1084,12,95
        1085,12,96
        1086,11,97
        1087,11,98
        1088,10,97
        1089,10,98
        1090,9,99
        1091,8,100
        1092,7,101
        1093,6,101
        1094,6,102
        1095,7,102
        1096,6,103
        1097,5,102
        1098,4,103
        1099,5,103
        1100,5,103
        1101,6,102
        1102,6,103
        1103,7,103
        1104,8,103
        1105,8,104
        1106,7,103
        1107,8,103
        1108,9,104
        1109,9,104
        1110,9,103
        1111,10,103
        1112,9,103
        1113,8,104
        1114,7,105
        1115,7,104
        1116,8,103
        1117,7,103
        1118,7,103
        1119,6,104
        1120,7,105
        1121,8,105
        1122,7,106
        1123,7,106
        1124,8,105
        1125,9,106
        1126,10,105
        1127,11,104
        1128,12,103
        1129,11,104
        1130,11,104
        1131,11,103
        1132,12,104
        1133,13,104
        1134,14,103
        1135,13,102
        1136,13,101
        1137,12,100
        1138,12,99
        1139,12,99
        1140,13,100
        1141,14,101
        1142,14,102
        1143,14,102
        1144,14,102
        1145,13,101
        1146,14,102
        1147,14,103
        1148,14,103
        1149,13,104
        1150,13,103
        1151,14,103
        1152,13,102
        1153,14,101
        1154,15,102
        1155,14,102
        1156,14,101
        1157,14,101
        1158,14,100
        1159,13,99
        1160,13,99
        1161,12,98
        1162,12,97
        1163,11,98
        1164,10,99
        1165,10,100
        1166,9,101
        1167,10,102
        1168,10,101
        1169,10,101
        1170,10,102
        1171,11,102
        1172,10,101
        1173,10,100
        1174,11,99
        1175,12,100
        1176,12,101
        1177,12,101
        1178,11,100
        1179,11,100
        1180,10,100
        1181,9,99
        1182,8,98
        1183,8,99
        1184,9,98
        1185,8,98
        1186,9,97
        1187,10,96
        1188,11,95
        1189,11,95
        1190,11,95
        1191,11,95
        1192,11,95
        1193,11,96
        1194,11,95
        1195,12,94
        1196,12,95
        1197,13,96
        1198,14,95
        1199,15,96
        1200,14,95
        1201,14,94
        1202,15,95
        1203,15,96
        1204,16,97
        1205,16,96
        1206,16,97
        1207,17,97
        1208,17,97
        1209,16,98
        1210,15,98
        1211,14,97
        1212,13,96
        1213,14,95
        1214,14,96
        1215,15,97
        1216,16,96
        1217,17,96
        1218,17,96
        1219,18,97
        1220,18,98
        1221,19,97
        1222,20,98
        1223,20,97
        1224,21,98
        1225,21,98
        1226,21,99
        1227,20,98
        1228,20,99
        1229,19,99
        1230,20,100
        1231,19,99
        1232,18,99
        1233,19,99
        1234,19,98
        1235,19,99
        1236,18,100
        1237,18,99
        1238,17,100
        1239,16,100
        1240,15,100
        1241,14,100
        1242,13,100
        1243,13,99
        1244,13,100
        1245,13,99
        1246,14,98
        1247,14,98
        1248,14,99
        1249,13,99
        1250,13,99
        1251,13,98
        1252,14,98
        1253,13,99
        1254,14,99
        1255,13,99
        1256,13,98
        1257,12,99
        1258,13,99
        1259,14,98
        1260,14,98
        1261,14,99
        1262,13,100
        1263,13,99
        1264,12,98
        1265,13,97
        1266,14,96
        1267,15,95
        1268,14,96
        1269,15,97
        1270,16,98
        1271,17,98
        1272,18,97
        1273,17,98
        1274,16,98
        1275,15,97
        1276,15,98
        1277,14,97
        1278,15,97
        1279,16,97
        1280,17,97
        1281,18,97
        1282,19,98
        1283,19,98
        1284,20,98
        1285,21,98
        1286,20,97
        1287,19,97
        1288,20,98
        1289,20,97
        1290,21,96
        1291,20,97
        1292,19,97
        1293,20,97
        1294,21,98
        1295,20,99
        1296,19,98
        1297,20,97
        1298,19,98
        1299,19,99
        1300,18,99
        1301,19,99
        1302,20,100
        1303,20,100
        1304,19,100
        1305,18,101
        1306,19,100
        1307,18,99
        1308,19,99
        1309,19,98
        1310,18,97
        1311,18,97
        1312,17,96
        1313,18,95
        1314,17,95
        1315,16,94
        1316,16,95
        1317,16,95
        1318,15,94
        1319,16,93
        1320,17,92
        1321,17,93
        1322,18,92
        1323,18,93
        1324,19,93
        1325,19,94
        1326,18,93
        1327,19,92
        1328,18,92
        1329,17,93
        1330,18,93
        1331,17,92
        1332,17,93
        1333,16,94
        1334,16,93
        1335,17,94
        1336,16,94
        1337,16,94
        1338,16,93
        1339,15,93
        1340,15,92
        1341,14,92
        1342,15,93
        1343,16,92
        1344,15,93
        1345,14,94
        1346,14,93
        1347,13,93
        1348,14,92
        1349,15,93
        1350,14,92
        1351,13,93
        1352,14,92
        1353,14,92
        1354,13,91
        1355,13,91
        1356,14,91
        1357,14,91
        1358,14,92
        1359,15,91
        1360,14,92
        1361,15,92
        1362,15,93
        1363,14,93
        1364,15,93
        1365,14,92
        1366,15,92
        1367,15,91
        1368,16,92
        1369,16,91
        1370,17,90
        1371,18,89
        1372,19,88
        1373,19,87
        1374,18,88
        1375,19,87
        1376,20,87
        1377,20,87
        1378,19,86
        1379,20,86
        1380,20,85
        1381,19,85
        1382,18,86
        1383,17,87
        1384,16,87
        1385,16,87
        1386,17,88
        1387,16,89
        1388,17,89
        1389,18,90
        1390,19,89
        1391,18,89
        1392,18,88
        1393,18,87
        1394,18,87
        1395,18,86
        1396,17,85
        1397,16,86
        1398,15,87
        1399,14,88
        1400,13,87
        1401,12,86
        1402,11,86
        1403,10,85
        1404,9,85
        1405,8,84
        1406,8,85
        1407,8,85
        1408,9,86
        1409,9,86
        1410,9,86
        1411,9,87
        1412,9,88
        1413,8,88
        1414,8,87
        1415,7,87
        1416,6,87
        1417,6,87
        1418,7,87
        1419,7,88
        1420,7,89
        1421,8,89
        1422,8,89
        1423,8,90
        1424,7,89
        1425,8,90
        1426,8,89
        1427,7,90
        1428,8,91
        1429,7,90
        1430,7,91
        1431,8,90
        1432,9,91
        1433,8,91
        1434,9,90
        1435,8,91
        1436,7,92
        1437,8,92
        1438,9,92
        1439,9,93
        1440,10,93
</pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'x'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                allButtonsEnabled: true,
                buttons: [{
                    count: 60,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '60M'
                }, {
                    count: 24,
                    type: 'hour',
                    text: '24H'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 0
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Activity'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Data input from CSV'
            },

            data: {
                csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
            },

            yAxis: [{
                opposite: false
            }, {
                opposite: true
            }],

            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: 'Minutes'
                },
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    minute: '%M',
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointStart: 0, // start date
                    pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 1, // data every 1 minutes
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                }
            },
            series: [{
                yAxis: 1,
                type: 'line',
            }, { yAxis: 0 },]
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that in Highharts for datetime axes, the X value is the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970. So your values are not minutes yet milliseconds.

To achieve what you want you have to map the CSV data to make the minute timestamps and change the way xAxis labels and tooltip content present points dates. Check the demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: 'Minutes'
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      minute: '%M',
      hour: '%H:%M',
      day: '%H:%M',
      week: '%e. %b',
      month: '%b \'%y',
      year: '%Y'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        const points = this.points;

        return [
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.x),
        'Series1: ' + points[0].y,
        'Series2: ' + points[1].y
      ];
    },
    split: true
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hkrs4c3t/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter
- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats
- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/data.csv

Comment: Is that same effect not achievable without the csv data mapping? Since my CSVs can have a variable amount of columns. It also seems to set the interval to 15 min resulting in fewer entries.

Comment: Yes, it is. I mapped it to have minutes instead of milliseconds, yet you can swap them directly into data source. There are fewer entries because of `dataGrouping` - https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.